# TYPO3 6.2 / Extension-Manager: "static_info_tables was requested to be downloaded in different versions"

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

i have a wired problem with TYPO3. We update a TYPO3 instance from **TYPO3 4.7** to **TYPO3 6.2.4**. If we go to the Extension-Manager in the Backend its workling well. If i go to 
**Get Extensions** on top the system loads a new list of Extensions.

Its running some minutes. After that in the box below i get the output **No packages found**.

If i click again on the **Extension-Manager** again. Its running 1 - 2 Minutes and i get the error:

```
Uncaught TYPO3 Exception
#1342432101: static_info_tables was requested to be downloaded in different versions. (More information)

TYPO3\CMS\Extensionmanager\Exception\ExtensionManagerException thrown in file
D:\www\xxxx\typo3\sysext\extensionmanager\Classes\Domain\Model\DownloadQueue.php in line 69.
```

I have checked that line.

```
if (array_key_exists($extension->getExtensionKey(), $this->extensionStorage[$stack])) {
    if ($this->extensionStorage[$stack][$extension->getExtensionKey()] !== $extension) {
        throw new \TYPO3\CMS\Extensionmanager\Exception\ExtensionManagerException(
            $extension->getExtensionKey() . ' was requested to be downloaded in different versions.',
            1342432101
        );
    }
}
```

If i comment the line the Extension-Manager load after a few minutes. Its very slow. Under Windows its not the fastest but normally its running.

If you output the Versions in the if statement then you get different versions **static_info_tables 6.0.10** and **static_info_tables 6.1.0** which is the correct one.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem? I can't use the Extension-Manager because its not loading and very very slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok after a few days we have found a solution. The extension table is corrupt after getting all new versions we have removed all old entries in the extension manager table and it was working well.

To solve the problem Find all entries in the **tx_extensionmanager_domain_model_extension** table for the extension key **static_info_tables**. After that you get some entries with different versions. We have removed all old entries that have made some trouble.

To find entries that make trouble you go to this line:

`D:\www\xxxx\typo3\sysext\extensionmanager\Classes\Domain\Model\DownloadQueue.php in line 69.`

And debug the if statement above. There you get the ids to remove.